# When i use th:action and method attribute together in form tag in Thymeleaf, it is giving me exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is very weird that when i th:action and method attribute in form tag, it is giving me exceptions but when i remove method attribute from the form tag, no exception occur. What i mean is
When is use

```
<form id="deliveryAddressForm" action="#" th:action="@{/product/save-address}" method="post" th:object="${address}">
```

**Exception occurs**

```
<form id="deliveryAddressForm" action="#" th:action="@{/product/save-address}" th:object="${address}">
```

**No exception after removing method="post"**

I don't understand why it is behaving like this.

**Please find the code attached below**

1. Html Code

```html
<form id="deliveryAddressForm" action="#" th:action="@{/product/save-address}" method="post" th:object="${address}">
                                        <!-- Invoice Address-->
                                        <h3 class="mb-4"> Invoice address</h3>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="fullname_invoice">Full Name</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Joe Black" id="fullname_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="emailaddress_invoice">Email Address</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="joe.black@gmail.com" id="emailaddress_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="phonenumber_invoice">Phone Number</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{mobile}" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phonenumber_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="street_invoice">Street</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{street}" placeholder="123 Main St." id="street_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="city_invoice">City</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{city}" placeholder="City" id="city_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="zip_invoice">Pincode</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{pincode}" placeholder="Postal code" id="zip_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label class="form-label" for="state_invoice">Land Mark</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{landmark}" placeholder="State" id="state_invoice">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-12 mt-3">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                    <input class="custom-control-input" id="show-shipping-address" type="checkbox" name="clothes-brand">
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label align-middle" for="show-shipping-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#shippingAddress">Use a different shipping address</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /Invoice Address-->
                                        <!-- Shippping Address-->
                                        <div class="collapse" id="shippingAddress">
                                            <h3 class="my-4">Shipping address </h3>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="form-label" for="street_shipping">Street</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{street1}" placeholder="123 Main St." id="street_shipping">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="form-label" for="city_shipping">City</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{city1}" placeholder="City" id="city_shipping">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="form-label" for="zip_shipping">Pin</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{pincode1}" placeholder="Postal code" id="zip_shipping">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="form-label" for="state_shipping">Land Mark</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{landmark1}" placeholder="State" id="state_shipping">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <label class="form-label" for="phonenumber_shipping">Phone Number</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{mobile1}" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phonenumber_shipping">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /Shipping Address-->
                                        <div class="my-5 d-flex justify-content-between flex-column flex-lg-row"><a class="btn btn-link text-muted" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left mr-2"></i>Back </a><a class="btn btn-dark forward-btn" data-pan="1" href="javascript:void(0)" id="saveDeliveryAddressForm">Choose delivery method<i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-2"></i></a></div>
                                    </form>
```

2. Model

```
    package com.ij.ikimall.bean;


    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;
@Component
public class AddressBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String pincode;
    private String landmark;
    private String mobile1;
    private String street1;
    private String city1;
    private String pincode1;
    private String landmark1;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getLandmark() {
        return landmark;
    }

    public void setLandmark(String landmark) {
        this.landmark = landmark;
    }

    public String getMobile1() {
        return mobile1;
    }

    public void setMobile1(String mobile1) {
        this.mobile1 = mobile1;
    }

    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    public String getCity1() {
        return city1;
    }

    public void setCity1(String city1) {
        this.city1 = city1;
    }

    public String getPincode1() {
        return pincode1;
    }

    public void setPincode1(String pincode1) {
        this.pincode1 = pincode1;
    }

    public String getLandmark1() {
        return landmark1;
    }

    public void setLandmark1(String landmark1) {
        this.landmark1 = landmark1;
    }
}
```

3. controller

```
@GetMapping("/checkout/{productEncId}")
    public String checkout(@PathVariable(value = "productEncId")String productEncId,Model model) {
        Product product = productService.findByEncryptedId(productEncId);
        model.addAttribute("productEncId",productEncId);
        AddressBean address = new AddressBean();
        model.addAttribute("address",address);
        return "view/checkout";
    }
```

**Also please find the detail exceptions generated**

```
2020-08-28 15:51:08.507 ERROR 20228 --- [nio-8989-exec-8] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8989-exec-8] Exception processing template "view/checkout": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/view/checkout.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/view/checkout.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template: "view/checkout" - line 41, col 79)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template: "view/checkout" - line 41, col 79)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2999) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
2020-08-28 15:51:08.524 ERROR 20228 --- [nio-8989-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/view/checkout.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2999) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]

2020-08-28 15:51:08.640 ERROR 20228 --- [nio-8989-exec-8] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/product/checkout/fvssrg5OLcM=] and exception [An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/view/checkout.html]")] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
```

Comment: Did you overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions on SO explaining similar problems but most of them had no answers apart from this answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982246/spring-thymeleaf-throws-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-com).

I inspected the issue further in my case, every time JSESSIONID was not set or modified manually, this error would appear.

I did some tiny experiments to figure out in which case the issue would go away:

1. Using Session creation policy ALWAYS would make the problem go away by always generating a session.

```
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
```

2. Using csrf token repository (as described in [Spring Security Issue 3906](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3906)) also helps to persist the csrf token (without using lazy persistence) by eagerly creating it. Also the **CookieCsrfTokenRepository** may be used.

```
    .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
```

With anonymous user, the application only generates session if required and hence, requesting a CSRF token when rendering a form can cause this issue in certain conditions such as rendering the form late in a long html file.

Comment: You not only suggested ways to solve the problem, but also explained why errors of this kind occur. This is a great answer, you helped a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Error says org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//view/checkout.html]")

Note the double // before view. Try removing / before view in your return statement

Comment: Hi Patrick, that was a mistake but now the error changes to An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/view/checkout.html]") and everything remains the same.

Comment: Did you updated the error-message in your original post? Could you also mark the line of code that is indicated in the error-message?

Comment: Hi Flocke, I just updated the error message. I apologise for not updating earlier. Also the issue occurs in html code on this  <form id="deliveryAddressForm" action="#" th:action="@{/product/save-address}" method="post" th:object="${address}">
  . After i remove method="post", error disappears

Answer (score 0):

Based on @sbsatter's answer I managed to solve my problem. I had to modify the code a bit due to some `depricated` flags. For Spring Boot 3.x it would look more like:

```java
 http.authorizeHttpRequests(
      requests -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll())
      .sessionManagement(sm ->  
          sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
      )
      .csrf(csrf ->
          csrf.csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
      );
```